# How to speed up writing a file to a WifiClient?

Tags: web-server, time, http, performance

I'm working with a Realtek Ameba IoT RTL8195 board that's compatible to Arduino.

I have a text file on an SD card that I want to send via HTTP over wifi, with the Ameba acting as a server.

I combined the [SD card example](http://www.amebaiot.com/en/ameba-arduino-sdio-edit/) with the [web server example](http://www.amebaiot.com/en/ameba-arduino-ameba-web-server/). There's no LED involved here.

Upon request from a client, I want to shove the whole content of the text file into a `text/plain` response as quickly as possible. At the moment i have a 18.7KB dummy file that takes 6.3s to download in the broswer total. That's rather slow.

My code looks essentially like this:

```
while (file.available() > 0)
{
    client.print((char)file.read());
}
client.flush();
```

Where `file` is declared as `SdFatFile file = fs.open(absolute_filename);` and `client` is `WiFiClient client = server.available();`. Which are both classes that come with the Ameba Arduino SDK.

Both of them extend `Stream`. I wonder if reading and writing both streams byte by byte causes a bottleneck. is there a way to simply write "the whole thing" to `client`?

Comment: You may try if doing it line by line is faster. Or in chunks of 500bytes (or whatever amount of RAM you have available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul's suggestion from the comment worked. Increasing the buffer reduced the overall time to a couple hundred ms.